# Zip command for excluding directories and files

Tags: ssh, directory, centos, zip

i'm trying to use this ssh command in centos 5 to zip up a directory full up folders and files yet exclude the examples below.  it's not working.

```bash
zip -r file.zip * -x dir1 -x dir2 -x file1 -x file2
```

or this one

```bash
zip -r file.zip * -x "dir1" -x "dir2" -x "file1" -x "file2"
```

It still just zips up the whole directory and everything it in.  I don't want dir1 dir2 file1 file2.

I need to know the right -x syntax for the exclude functions to work.

Comment: yes it is a programming question for an ssh script.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [Unix zip directory but excluded specific subdirectories](https://superuser.com/q/312301/173513), [how to exclude directories and file zipping a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/371579), [How to exclude a directory when zipping files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219101/56041), etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-x` option is a bit strange; you list the files, starting with `-x`, and ending with an `@` sign:

```
zip file.zip -r * -x dir1 dir2 file1 file2 @
```

I also seriously doubt you want `\` in your filenames on a Unix system … make sure your paths are OK. `/` is the usual path separator.

Example:

```
mkdir tmp5
cd tmp5
touch a b c d e f g
zip foo.zip -r * -x e f g @
  adding: a (stored 0%)
  adding: b (stored 0%)
  adding: c (stored 0%)
  adding: d (stored 0%)
```

With subdirectories, you can easily omit their *contents* using a wildcard, but it seems that the `*` causes the directory itself to be included (empty):

```
mkdir x y z
touch {a,b,c} {x,y,z}/{a,b,c}
zip foo.zip -r * -x c y y/* z z/* @
  adding: a (stored 0%)
  adding: b (stored 0%)
  adding: x/ (stored 0%)
  adding: x/b (stored 0%)
  adding: x/a (stored 0%)
  adding: x/c (stored 0%)
  adding: y/ (stored 0%)
  adding: z/ (stored 0%)
```

You might to better to omit the `*` and explicitly list those things you *do* want included…

```
zip core-latest-$version.zip -r cp images include mobile stats \
    -x cp/includes/configure.php @
```

(the `\` at the end just continues to the next line; you can put it all on one line without the trailing `\`)

Comment: ok, weird.  I got the backslashes from about.com they did some sort of -x \\*.0 for excluding all files that end in .0.  no idea.  anyway i tried your command and it still didn't work.  Here's my actual command.
zip core-latest.zip -r * -x templates -x stats -x cp/includes/configure.php @

Comment: Should only need the one `-x` at the head and the one `@` at the end… and, are you really running `zip` from inside the directory that you're zipping?

Comment: here my script:
echo -n "enter new version (v1-1)"
read version
cd /home/core/www/
rm -rf core-latest-*.zip
zip core-latest-$version.zip -r * -x templates stats cp/includes/configure.php @
chown -R core.core core-latest-$version.zip

Comment: It's just more usual to be up a level, so that your ZIP contains a top-level folder. Not "wrong," just unusual. Looks good, and seems to work for me.

Comment: you mean zip up the www dir?  It's for a php program we want to install on other servers for download where they would drop it in their www or public_html dir and unzip it and be done.

Comment: would it matter if there were contents inside the templates and stats directories?  I want it all excluded, the folder and its contents.

Comment: here a directory listing inside the www or public_html directory.  cache cp images includes mobile stats temp templates

Comment: ok, the last one actually sort of worked...but the problem now is that I have about 100 files in the root directory not getting zipped.  it just zips the directories with that command.

Comment: Ah. You didn't mention random files there — they weren't in the listing you gave; You could enumerate them, exclude using `-x dir/* @` to strip out directories you don't want to zip, or … well, if your app is littering the root directory with 100 files, maybe it's time for a clean-up of the codebase to make less of a mess? :-) One gimmick: If your filenames have dots and directories don't, you could perhaps add `*.*` to the included list. Unlike DOS/Windows, this will only include files with a literal `.` in their name, so it will skip files/dirs without it (like `templates`)

Answer (score 21):

For my particular system in order to exclude a directory I had to put quotes around my excluded directories and it worked like a charm:

```bash
zip -r myarchive.zip target -x "target/exclude1/*" "target/exclude2/*"
```

Notes:

-- this excluded both the directory to exclude and all files inside it.

-- You must use the full path to the directories you want to include and exclude!

-- As long as the excludes are at the end of the line you do not need the @ symbol

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using putty, please follow following steps:

1. Enter your directory: `$ cd directory_name` and press enter
2. Write command:

   ```
   $ zip -r file_name.zip . -x \*excludingfolderName\*
   ```

After `zip` Use `.` for current directory, `*` is a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR;

> Use `-x "**/folder/*"`

#### LR;

You can use the same syntax as `gitignore` or vscode exclude files
[vscode files exclude syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJa3y.png)